# При перемещении элемента меняется ширина

Tags: css, jquery-ui

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myOrders table').sortable();
});
```

```css
.myOrders table {
  width: 100%;
}

.myOrders .item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
}

.myOrders .item td {
  border: solid 1px #E1E1E1;
  text-align: center;
}

.myOrders .item:hover {
  background: #DFEFFF;
  color: #000;
}

.myOrders .OrdersTitle {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00274E;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: move;
  text-align: center;
}

.OrdersTitle {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myOrders">
  <table>
    <tbody class="myOrders_categories">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="OrdersTitle">
          Categories 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="myOrders_categories">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="OrdersTitle">
          Categories 2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          Item1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item2
        </td>
        <td>
          Item3
        </td>
        <td>
          Item4
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Пример JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po3ous7h/)

Как сделать чтобы при перемещении ширина  не менялась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допишите вот это:

```
.ui-sortable-helper {
   display: table;
}
```